# Spread types may only be created from object type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this JavaScript code which I want to use into TypeScript project. But I get these errors. Do you know how I can fix these issues?

```
const next = () => {
        const data = {
            currency,
            iban,
            confirmIban
        }

        history.push({
            pathname: '/summary',
            state: { ...location.state, ...data }
        })
    }
```

For this line `state: { ...location.state, ...data }` I get `TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.`

```
                   <TextField label="Your test" variant="outlined" onChange={(e) => {
                        setTest(e.target.value)
                    }} />
```

For this line `(e)` I get `TS7006: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

EDIT: complete code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container, FormControl, Typography, Grid, TextField, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import SelectOption from '../../components/Navbar/Select/SelectOption';

export default function BankDetails() {
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState();
    const [iban, setIban] = useState();
    const [confirmIban, setConfirmIban] = useState();

    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();

    const next = () => {
        const data = {
            currency,
            iban,
            confirmIban
        }

        history.push({
            pathname: '/summary',
            state: { ...location.state, ...data }
        })
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <Typography variant="h4">Select an account for payouts</Typography>

            <FormControl>
                <Grid xs={12}>
                    <SelectOption handleValue={(e) => {
                        setCurrency(e.target.value)
                    }}>
                        <option value="">Select your currency</option>
                        <option value="lev">USD</option>
                    </SelectOption>
                </Grid>

                <Grid xs={12}>
                    <label>IBAN</label>
                    <TextField label="Your number" variant="outlined" onChange={(e) => {
                        setIban(e.target.value)
                    }} />
                </Grid>

                <Grid xs={12}>
                    <label>Confirm USD</label>
                    <TextField label="Confirm your USD" variant="outlined" onChange={(e) => {
                        setConfirmIban(e.target.value)
                    }} />
                </Grid>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={next}>
                    Continue
                </Button>
            </FormControl>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: We dont have enough information to answer this question. We need you to post more code please

Comment: Is your `location.state` an object ?

Comment: I added the whole page.

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(location.state) ? is it an object ?

Comment: This is the state: `export interface Location<S = LocationState> {
    pathname: Pathname;
    search: Search;
    state: S;
    hash: Hash;
    key?: LocationKey | undefined;
}`

Answer (score 2):

**1. TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.**

for this one, you should write your push state with an object.

**Note:** you should know that `location.state` is `undefined` for first and you are using `...location.state` in the object but you don't know your state is an object or not. so you should write a simple condition for that.

```
let prevState = {}
if (location.state) {
    prevState = { ...location.state as {} }
}
history.push({
    pathname: '/summary',
    state: { ...prevState, ...data }
})
```

**2. TS7006: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

for these parameters, you can simply write `any` type.

```
<SelectOption handleValue={(e: any) => {
    setCurrency(e.target.value)
}}>
```

Or you can add this rule to your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this aproach, let me know if works.

```js
export interface Location<S = LocationState> {
  pathname: Pathname;
  search: Search;
  state: S as object; 
  hash: Hash;
  key?: LocationKey | undefined;
}

export interface Location<S = LocationState> {
  pathname: Pathname;
  search: Search;
  state: Object.assign({}, S);
  hash: Hash;
  key?: LocationKey | undefined;
}
```

```html
import { FormEvent } from "react";


<TextField 
  label="Your test"
  variant="outlined"
  onChange={(e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>):  => setTest(e.target.value) />
```

Comment: For `  onChange={(e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>):  => setTest(e.target.value) /> 
` I get ` TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`

Comment: Try this `e.currentTarget.value` you can learn more here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget